# how to get the same jquery hover effect for this social icons?

Tags: jquery, blogger, easing, rollover-effect

How can I get the same jQuery hover effect (easing) like that in [the Epione blogger template](http://epione-fbt.blogspot.com/)?

I've tried so many ways to put it into my blog but I think I'm noob in jQuery Animation codes.

I will be very grateful if you can help me in this.

HTML Code

```
<div id='get_social'>
<div class='get_social_wrap'>
    <a class='follow_fb_link' href='http://www.facebook.com/facebook-id' title='follow us on facebook'/>
    <a class='follow_twitter_link' href='http://twitter.com/twetter-id' title='follow us on twitter'/>
    <a class='follow_rss_link' href='/feeds/posts/default' title='subscribe to our rss feed'/>

 </a></a></a></div>
```

CSS Code

```
#get_social{float:left; position:relative; margin:0px;}
.get_social_wrap{ position:relative; width:160px; margin-top:15px;}

.follow_fb_link{width:22px; height:22px; background:url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cKUUmDR1mkw/ThsIt1kAzlI/AAAAAAAABOQ/PFgbBB1e0VQ/s1600/ep_fb.png) no-repeat; float:left; margin-right:7px;}
.follow_twitter_link{width:22px; height:22px; background:url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ne3mIs7NGqk/ThsIuqNTIjI/AAAAAAAABOg/kIbh7Z9A96E/s1600/ep_twitter.png) no-repeat;  margin-right:7px; float:left;}
.follow_rss_link{width:22px; height:22px; background:url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-V_MuLwEucB0/ThsIuOcu7OI/AAAAAAAABOY/4jyEVTewJQM/s1600/ep_feed.png) no-repeat; margin-right:7px; float:left;}
```

jQuery Easing Plugin

```
<script src='http://my-subtitles-blog.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.easing.1.3.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys for your answers,
i found the problem. it was that i need to add the (jQuery Background Position Animation Plugin) and all works fine
you can download it from here

http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

and the Easing Plugin from here

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

### The Final Code will be like this, Enjoy :)

```
<script src='/jquery.easing.1.3.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='jquery.backgroundpos.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function(){
var easing = &#39;easeOutBounce&#39;;
$(&#39;.follow_fb_link, .follow_twitter_link, .follow_rss_link&#39;).css({backgroundPosition: &#39;0px 0px&#39;})
    .mouseover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:&#39;0 -22px&#39;},200, easing)
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:&#39;0 0&#39;},200, easing)
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

All they're doing is having a picture such as these:

[image: Facebook Icons] [image: Twitter Icons] [image]

as the background, and then animate the background position on hover.

---

Here's the relevant piece of code from their site:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var easing = 'easeOutBounce';
    jQuery('.follow_fb_link, .follow_twitter_link, .follow_rss_link').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'})
        .mouseover(function(){
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'0 -22px'},200, easing)
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            jQuery(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition:'0 0'},200, easing)
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What he is doing is animating the background position on the a tag and using 'elastic' (I think). So it would be something like:

```
$('get_social_wrap a').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition :  '50% 25px'
    }, 'easeInOutElastic');
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundPosition :  '50% 0px'
    }, 'easeInOutElastic');
});
```

learn more about animation syntax and easing here http://api.jquery.com/animate/.