# Bounce effect to sprite icon using easing1.3.js

Tags: jquery, css, sprite, easing

I try to apply a bounce vertical effect to my social nav icon using [jQuery Easing](http://easings.net) but I'm not familiar with js and so I need some help.

HTML

```
<ul class="social">
    <li class="facebook"><a class="bounce" href="http://facebook.com"></a></li>
    <li class="twitter"><a class="bounce" href="http://twitter.com"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.social li a {
  float: left;
  height: 28px;
  width: 30px;        
  display: inline-block; 
  background: url("http://s14.postimg.org/ufud6x5n1/social.png") no-repeat;
}
ul.social li.facebook a {
  background-position: 0 0;
}
ul.social li.twitter a {
  background-position: -30px 0;
}
ul.social li.facebook a:hover {
  background-position: 0 -28px;
}
ul.social li.twitter a:hover {
  background-position: -30px -28px;
}
```

And here is my problem.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.bounce').hover( function() {
    $(this).animation(1000, "easeOutBounce");
  });
});
```

How can I do to make the background bouncing on mouse hover and then apply a "normal" ease effect on mouse out?

I made a CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/VLYqdL)

Any help will be much appreciate :)
(...and sorry for my not good english)

Comment: $(this).animation(1000, "easeOutBounce"}); must be  $(this).animation(1000, "easeOutBounce");

Comment: oops, sorry, my mistake. I made the correction. My question is still open but thanks for your comment Grumpy.

Answer (score 0):

This works except in Firefox. Still investigating...

```
 $(".bounce").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y':'-28px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});
$(".bounce").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'background-position-y':'0'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'linear'})
});
```

EDIT: Ok, I found my answer:
1. Using [jQuery Background Position Animation Plugin](http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html) (Found that answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7396445/how-to-get-the-same-jquery-hover-effect-for-this-social-icons))
2. And this works also with Firefox

```
$(".bounce-fb").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'0 -28px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});
$(".bounce-fb").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'0 0'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'linear'})
});

$(".bounce-tw").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'-30px -28px'},{queue:false, duration:600, easing: 'easeOutBounce'})
});
$(".bounce-tw").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'backgroundPosition':'-30px 0'},{queue:false, duration:800, easing: 'linear'})
});
```

Everything is working as I wanted now. See [DEMO](http://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/VLYqdL)